# Echo key value from array returned from a function in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, function

Sorry if this is a bit of a noob question, am still a beginner on php....

I need to echo the Country key from an array returned from a function.
I have tried various way of trying to get the value I am wanting from the array, but each time do not get the results I want.

I want to set the 'country' value from the returned array to a variable to do an if argument on the value. Please help...

sample of what Im trying to do below -

```
<?php

$country = get_shipping_address()['country']

if ( $country=="GB" ) {

do this;

}

?>
```

Below is the function -

```
function get_shipping_address() {

    if ( ! $this->shipping_address ) {

         if ( $this->shipping_address_1 ) {

             // Formatted Addresses
             $address = array(
                 'address_1'     => $this->shipping_address_1,
                 'address_2'     => $this->shipping_address_2,
                 'city'          => $this->shipping_city,
                 'state'         => $this->shipping_state,
                 'postcode'      => $this->shipping_postcode,
                 'country'       => $this->shipping_country
              );

              $joined_address = array();

             foreach ( $address as $part ) {

                  if ( ! empty( $part ) ) {
                      $joined_address[] = $part;
                  }
             }

            $this->shipping_address = implode( ', ', $joined_address );
        }
     }

     return $this->shipping_address;
 }
```

Comment: You are not returning an array, your are returning a string `$this->shipping_address = implode( ', ', $joined_address );`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that you're doing this in your function:

```
foreach ( $address as $part ) {
    if ( ! empty( $part ) ) {
        $joined_address[] = $part;
    }
}
$this->shipping_address = implode( ', ', $joined_address );
```

What that does, is makes a `string` with all the values of your array. Example:

```
derp, derp, derp, derp, derp, derp
```

What you want is to return the `$address variable`.

```
return $address;
```

Making your function look like this:

```
function get_shipping_address() {
    $address = array();

    if (!$this->shipping_address) {

        if ($this->shipping_address_1) {

            // Formatted Addresses
            $address = array(
                'address_1' => $this->shipping_address_1,
                'address_2' => $this->shipping_address_2,
                'city' => $this->shipping_city,
                'state' => $this->shipping_state,
                'postcode' => $this->shipping_postcode,
                'country' => $this->shipping_country
            );

        }
    }

    return $address;
}
```

Comment: won't be `$address` undefined in cases when `if's` conditions evaluate to false?

Comment: @Verhaeren That it will, but unless the OP can specify any need to cover that aspect, this answer covers his scope :)

Comment: Or `address` can have a default value as soon as the function starts.

Comment: Done, and it has a default empty array.

Comment: Good, but he also can get a `undefined index` error when he tries to check the returned array like this `get_shipping_address()['country']`.

Comment: That's entirely up to him, when he replies, we'll go from there.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Darren, ( and everyone else that commented )
That done the trick.

I have created a new function and changed it to only return the value I am needing, as I just need to know the country value. 
So have changed the function as below.
Thanks for the help!!

```
function get_my_shipping_address() {

    if ( ! $this->shipping_address ) {

        if ( $this->shipping_address_1 ) {

            // Formatted Addresses
            $address = array(
                'address_1'     => $this->shipping_address_1,
                'address_2'     => $this->shipping_address_2,
                'city'          => $this->shipping_city,
                'state'         => $this->shipping_state,
                'postcode'      => $this->shipping_postcode,
                'country'       => $this->shipping_country
            );
        }
    }

    return $address['country'];
}
```